# Contentful API returning 'version mismatch' on entry update

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, contentful

I'm attempting to do the following with the Content Management API for Contentful:

1. Get an entry (entry1)
2. Find another entry (entry2) using data from a field in entry1
3. Update entry1 with data from entry2

My code looks like this:

```
client.getSpace("xxxxxxxx").then(function(space){
  space.getEntries({
    "content_type": "xxxxxxxx",
    "sys.id": "2KEZYJOgDSeQMCQIE0Oo88",
    "limit": 1
  }).then(function(places){

    //search for relevant category entry
    space.getEntries({
      "content_type": contentType.category,
      "sys.id": places[0].fields.category["en-GB"],
      "limit": 1
    }).then(function(category){

      //update place object
      places[0].fields.categoryNew = {
        "en-GB": [ 
          { sys: { type: "Link", linkType: "Entry", id: category[0].sys.id } } 
        ]
      };        

      //update place
      request({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'https://api.contentful.com/spaces/xxxxxxxx/entries/' + places[0].sys.id,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxx',
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json',
          'X-Contentful-Content-Type': 'xxxxxxxx'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({fields:places[0].fields})
      }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
      });

    });


  });
});
```

Steps 1 and 2 work fine but the final step, updating the original entry, keeps returning the following error:

```
Response: {
  "sys": {
    "type": "Error",
    "id": "VersionMismatch"
  },
  "requestId": "content-api:2PSSF6RtpSs2YyaaisK2wc"
}
```

How do I stop this happening? I've tried everything I can think of including manually updating the `sys.version` number, but when updating it seems to ignore any `sys` data I provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/introduction/updating-and-version-locking

You need to pass the version as a header parameter called "X-Contentful-Version" with the PUT request.

Comment: this is a 404... :(

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, you are missing the `X-Contentful-Version` header but that's possibly not the cause of the problem.

Contentful wants the "current version" (as per [docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/introduction/updating-and-version-locking)), which is not necessarily the same as the published version. It wants to check that you are not updating an old version of the content. Both the latest (i.e. "current") version and the published version are present in the response to GET for an entry. Make sure you use the correct one in the `X-Contentful-Version` header or you will get this error. If you use one of the official SDKs, it should handle this for you automatically. But if you are using e.g. Golang or curl, you'll have to do it yourself as above.

It may also be a PATCH request that you need here rather than PUT but that's a different matter.