# Updating entry of Contentful using postman

Tags: postman, put, contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

As you can check below screenshot I tried to make PUT api call in the Contentful to update the entry.

When I try to hit GET call, everything works fine but don't understand here what is reason of this below error while making PUT call.

Did I missed anything here or anything wrong here?

NOTE: I changed all the variable while making call, spaceId, env, entryId and authorisation(passing access_token)

[image: put api call for Contentful using postman]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see in your URL, it looks like you are trying to hit the `Contentful Preview API`, which is read-only.

> API Base URL https://preview.contentful.com
> This is a read-only API

[source](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-preview-api/)

Therefore, updating an entry via a `PUT` request cannot be done with the url you are using.

---

However, I believe your `PUT` request should work if you update the base url to be `https://api.contentful.com/` instead. This is the endpoint for the `Content Management API`.

**Important note:**

- if you do this, you will need to use a [different auth token](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/authentication/#the-content-management-api) for the `Content Management API`.

---

Using `https://api.contentful.com/` hits the writable `Content Management API`, which has [documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entry/create-update-an-entry/console/curl) for the `PUT` request you are making.

Importing the corresponding [`curl` command](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entry/create-update-an-entry/console/curl) into your Postman client will confirm this.

---

So in the end, the url would be this:

[https://api.contentful.com/spaces/{space_id}/environments/{environment_id}/entries/{entry_id}](https://api.contentful.com/spaces/%7Bspace_id%7D/environments/%7Benvironment_id%7D/entries/%7Bentry_id%7D)

Again, the bearer token will have to come from the writable Content Management API.